# Change Oracle DB Workspace in datasource Connection JBOSS

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly

Here is the thing... I have the following datasource:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/GPET_JU1@des12gpe1" pool-name="GPET_JU1@des12gpe1" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//bla:9999/blablabla</connection-url>
    <driver>oracle</driver>
    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
    <security>
        <user-name>blablabla</user-name>
        <password>blablabla</password>
    </security>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
        <allow-multiple-users></allow-multiple-users>
    </pool>
    <validation>
        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"></exception-sorter>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>10</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
        <prepared-statement-cache-size>0</prepared-statement-cache-size>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
      **<new-connection-sql>
        Begin execute immediate 'CALL DBMS_WM.GotoWorkspace ("APP_TESTE_01")'; end;
    </new-connection-sql>**
</datasource>
```

I need to change the workspace from "LIVE" to "X", everytime this datasource is called to create a connection in database. I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06576: not a function or valid method
```

If I perform a select instead of trying to change the workspace, I dont get error but obviously it doesn't change the workspace like I wanted.

Any ideas in how I can manage to change the oracle db workspace using the datasource?

Comment: did you try with just `CALL DBMS_WM.GotoWorkspace ("APP_TESTE_01")`

Comment: I just got success by: Begin DBMS_WM.GotoWorkspace ('APP_TESTE_01'); end;

Answer (score 0):

Got success by the following:

```
<new-connection-sql>
    Begin DBMS_WM.GotoWorkspace ('APP_TESTE_01'); end;
</new-connection-sql>
```